# input for online programming competitons

Tags: c++

In many online programming competitons(ex. [codechef](http://codechef.com)) the input has 2-5 lines. Mainly the first line consists of no of test case and other lines containing the data for program.
**For Example:**

> Input: The first line of input contains an integer T, denoting the
>   number of test cases. Then T test cases follow. The first line of each
>   test case contains three space-separated integers N, K and Q as
>   described in the problem. The second line contains a string S of
>   length N. Then the next Q lines describe the query, where the ith line
>   of them contains two space-separated integers Li and Ri.
>
> 1
>
> 8 2 3
>
> 01110000
>
> 1 4
>
> 2 4
>
> 5
>   8

Now suppose in my code I take input for first line as

```
 cin>>no_of_case;
```

I run a for loop times the no of test cases I face the problem taking input from second line.

but as you can see in the input statement the 2nd line has 3 variable inputs.

**How can I take the input for 2nd line in 3 different variables?**

One way I found to take the input in an array and parse the data for spaces and separate the input into different variables. But that goes long for long inputs.

Comment: [Read the whole line](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), put the line in an [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) (with the help of e.g. [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)) to put into a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: If you don't know how to do this, it might be a little early to worry about online competitions...? Perhaps find a tutorial or three, or even a book.  If you want help here, you should post the code you've tried with the exact input and output (or compiler error if you don't get as far as running it), and what you don't understand about why it's failing.

Comment: What's wrong with `cin>>N>>K>>Q;`?

Comment: @Pushkar No, it reads three whitespace-delimited things.

Comment: @Pushkar, https://ideone.com/ZBCDTg

Comment: @deniss is right. If you have a fixed number of words you can just consecutively read them with cin (or `scanf("%d")`). The amount and nature separating the words is irrelevant for these routines, precisely in order to make input like this robust.

Comment: oh! it did work. I was'nt sure about it. anyways now I know it. Anyone put It as a answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix:

```
cin>>N>>K>>Q;
```

That should work...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the algorithm you may be looking for:

Read all the inputs using `getline(cin, no_of_case)`, then split the inputs using a space (" ") as your delimiter.

Hope this gets you on the right track...

Note:  You may need to convert these strings back to integers if you plan on using the inputs as numbers for arithmetic purposes.

Edit:  To convert the string numbers back to integers you can use the `std::stoi()` function.  In this example use it like this: `std::stoi(no_of_case)`

Do make sure to have `#include <iostream>` and `#include <string>` as well, and the `std::` prefix isn't required if you're using namespaces.

Comment: that's where I face problem how do I convert them back to Integers

Comment: @Pushkar I've edited my answer to show how to convert strings back to integers...